# How do i type "⌃" on a QWERTZ (czech) keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I'd like to know how "⌃" is written on my keyboard, ive been trying but i cant figure it out.I know how to do it on a qwerty one but not on mine.

Comment: If your keyboard layout is set to match your keyboard, look down on your keyboard for that key. If its not there, then your keyboard does not support this. You can still add a different layout and switch to that, bu then the keys won't always match with what's on your keyboard.

Comment: OS-dependent question, OS not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The character `⌃` is accessible with the <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> combination on the Czech keyboard.